# Create Groups of Beginning to End numbers from a list in excel

Tags: list, excel, grouping, vba

For summing up, what I need is to do the opposite of this post:

[How to create a list from beginning number and end number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635800/how-to-create-a-list-from-beginning-number-and-end-number)

In other words I have a list of numbers in Column A and I wish to group them up in ranges from beginning to end numbers in columns B and C
i.e.

```
column A
1
2
3
6
7
8
25
28
29
30
```

(after executing VBA code)

```
Column B  Column C
   1         3
   6         8
   25        25
   28        30
```

In case the value cannot be grouped, it will be the same beginning and end number (as seen with N° 25 in above example)

Comment: Where's the part where you explain what numbers get grouped together? It looks like you're doing every 3rd number but then "25" kind of throws that off. So, explain how they are being grouped.

Comment: Just curious... [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: @David: I think the op wants the start and end of each set of consecutive numbers, e.g. 1-3, 6-8, 25, 28-30.

Comment: @glh ahhh you see a pattern that I didn't :)

Comment: The problem is that we only think that a given pattern is applicable here and we don't have a proof to that. The op didn't specify the pattern yet either.

Comment: @LajosArpad the ops link provides a similar issue but in reverse. although not written discreetly by the op my interpretation is correct.

Comment: I assume that is right, but I'm not 100% sure about it. The op should edit his/her question to get rid of any ambivalencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My quick tryout

```
Sub Ranges()
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim beg As Integer
    Dim en As Integer
    i = 1
    r = 1
    beg = .Cells(1, 1).Value
    en = beg
    While .Cells(i, 1).Value
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value > en + 1 Then
            .Cells(r, 2).Value = beg
            .Cells(r, 3).Value = en

            beg = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            en = beg
            r = r + 1
        Else
            en = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    .Cells(r, 2).Value = beg
    .Cells(r, 3).Value = en
End With
End Sub
```

Results

```
A   B   C
1   1   3
2   6   9
3   12  12
6   33  38
7   44  45
8   55  56
9   66  67
12      
33      
34      
35      
36      
37      
38      
44      
45      
55      
56      
66      
67
```

Comment: hi, ive tried using this on a long list of values (pretty much the entire column) and after a while it does give me some results and works like a charm, but suddenly it shows me "Run Time Error '6': Overflow"
had no luck on solving this, any suggestions?

Comment: Yea I think it will do funny things if the column filled to the end and when the loop tries look for a value outside of the sheets max row.  The "While" loop could use another condition to check the value of "i" at the end when it's being incremented. If it goes out of bounds then exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Tarmo Elfving has it right idea but can only handle numbers up to 32k. If you change the Integer to Long instead, the script can handle much bigger numbers while removing the "Overflow" error that many are seeing.

```
Sub Ranges()
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim r As Long
    Dim beg As Long
    Dim en As Long
    i = 1
    r = 1
    beg = .Cells(1, 1).Value
    en = beg
    While .Cells(i, 1).Value
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value > en + 1 Then
            .Cells(r, 2).Value = beg
            .Cells(r, 3).Value = en

            beg = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            en = beg
            r = r + 1
        Else
            en = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    .Cells(r, 2).Value = beg
    .Cells(r, 3).Value = en
End With
End Sub
```

Results

```
A       B       C
10001   10001   10003
10002   10006   10009
10003   100012  100012
10006   100033  100038
10007   100044  100045
10008   100055  100056
10009   100066  100067
100012      
100033      
100034      
100035      
100036      
100037      
100038      
100044      
100045      
100055      
100056      
100066      
100067
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
s as range
Set s = range("A1:A10")
r as long
r = 1
p as long
p = s.cells(1,1).value

for each c in s 

    'add start of range
    if c-1 <> p then

        'end last range
        If r>1 then

            cell(r, 3) = p
            r=r+1

        end if

        'start new range
        Cells(r, 2)=c

    End if
    p = c

Loop
Cells(r, 3)=s.cells(s.count, 1)
```